# What is the difference between the Environmental Variables for Windows System and PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

We set the Windows System Path variable via *System > Advanced System Settings > Environmental Variables > Path > Edit*.

We set the PowerShell ones via `Env:Path += ";Some\New\Path"`

What, if any, is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 5):

When you set the variable in powershell, it's set *in that process (and its children) only*. This is equivalent to using `SET` from the cmd prompt or a batch file.

In the dialog, you are setting the variables for the user (or for the system), which affects every process spawned under those contexts. This is analogous to using `SETX` from the cmd prompt or a batch file.

Comment: More precisely it's in that particular PowerShell process only (and its child processes spawned afterwards). "Session" could also refer to the the Windows logon session, which does not receive this environment change.

Comment: Quite right! I've updated my answer with better wording; thanks @AnsgarWiechers.

Comment: The SETX equivalent in PowerShell is `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Name','Value','Machine')`.